Nested loops for App Services and Web Apps in Bicep
Is there a way to use nested loops something like this in Bicep?
param deployLocation = '...'
param scope = ...
param webAppHostingPlan = [...]

// Deploy Web App Hosting Plans. This has an output of serverFarmId.
module webAppPlan 'modules/webAppPlan.bicep' = [for name in webAppHostingPlan: {
  name: '${name.value}'
  scope: resourceGroup(name.scope)
  params: {
    location:deployLocation
    name: name.value
  }
// deploy a Web App using this Plan. This doesn't work but I want something like this
  module webApp 'modules/webApp.bicep' = {
    scope: resourceGroup(scope)
    name: 'test name'
    location: deployLocation
    serverFarmId: webAppPlan.serverFarmId
  }
}
]


Nested loops is not directly possible in bicep. Instead you can create a separate individual files and add all them in a module file. @Lee

web.bicep

param sku string = 'F1' // The SKU of App Service Plan
param linuxFxVersion string = 'node|14-lts' // The runtime stack of web app
param location string = resourceGroup().location // Location for all resources
param appServicePlanName string
param webSiteName string

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: webSiteName
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
    }
  }
}


main.bicep
param webAppHostingPlan array = [
  {
    resourceGroupName: 'rg1'
    planName: 'plan1'
    siteName: 'site1'
  }
]

module webModule 'web.bicep' = [for (item, index) in webAppHostingPlan: {
  name: '${index}deployment'
  scope: resourceGroup(item.resourceGroupName)
  params: {
    appServicePlanName: item.planName
    webSiteName: item.siteName
  }
}]


